# How to limit the number of posts a user can publish based on user type

Tags: posts, count

I am creating a member only wordpress site that will restrict the number of custom posts a user can publish (Custom post type = contacts) based on their role.

I will have 4 roles:

Role 1 = 25 posts;

Role 2 = 150 posts;

Role 3 = 300 posts;

Role 4 = unlimited posts

Is this possible to do with WP hooks?

Comment: Where does a user create a custom post in your system? in the default WP Dashboard or do you have a form in the front-end?

Comment: Only in the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this plugin [Bainternet Posts Creation Limits](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bainternet-posts-creation-limits/) witch let you add how meny post a user, role or group can create. The plugin description says:

Main Feature:

- Limit number of any post type creation.
- Select Post Status to count. (NEW)
- **Limit number of any post type creation by user Role. (NEW)**
- Limit number of any post type creation by user ID. (NEW)
- New Limit Rule System (faster and stable).
- Custom blocked message For each Rule. (NEW)
- MultiSite Support. (Fixed and works better then before)
- ADD NEW Links are removed when limit is reached (NEW)
- 0 Now means ZERO so Its actually blocks the user from creating at
  all.
- Shortcode to limit front end post creation (NEW).

It looks like you have a function that matches your question: Limit number of any post type creation by user Role.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for finding this for me. Just installed and works as I was hoping.